# How to line-break cites correctly (hanging-over problem)?

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, citing

while using Bibtex, I experienced an frustrating issue with line-breaks on cites in my block text.

I have chosen to use the following bibtex implementation:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{library}
```

No voodoo here. 
Nevertheless, this leads to the following composition:

[image]

The cite is not line-broken correctly. I assume many other users have already experienced that hanging-over problem either.

Can someone help me how to fix that LaTeX is compiling the cite correctly in a way that it nicely integrates itself into block structure?

EDIT:
Rephrasing makes it hard to monitor the whole 300 pages every time I recompile the document due to some minor modifications. I know that many use suggest to rephrase the text but I would like to ask for a more professional solution here.

Comment: I thought about a more elegant way instead of making my sentence sounding not so nice anymore ;). Honestly, I think rephrasing makes it hard to monitor the whole 300 pages every time I recompile the document due to some minor modifications.

Comment: I think we are talking about the last fine tuning of your document.  I do this usually only one time, after I have **finished writing** my text with the final proofread of the document. With option `draft` you can find the hanging-over lines easily and rephrase them or insert (depends on the situation) a hyphenation mark.  The algorithm of LaTeX is very good, but some times it needs the help of you.  Until today a good typography needs the help of a person, the program allone can not manage it in the same way a learned typographer can ...

Comment: plain style alone doesn't give such citations. Beside this what do you want latex to do to handle the problem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I would like to latex do automatic line-breaking after commas or white space inside (very long) citations, and finally re-distributing letters to let them fit into block style.
Isn't there any extension already available which is doing exactly like this?: 1) Break after commas/whitespaces 2) Run latex' letter distribution algorithm for the related lines.

Comment: You should load microtype and you can loosen the settings of latex regarding line breaking see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull.